# Medieval fantasy book about a boy who finds a rock in a cave or something like that. He keeps it in his pocket 24/7 and it hatches into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons, medieval

Okay so I read this book, I'm pretty sure it was a book series as well, in 6th grade, so late 2010s.

What I can remember is that this boy (I think?) -- it's set in more of a medieval fantasy type setting -- finds a cool looking rock in a cave and keeps it in his pocket, maybe his coat pocket, and he keeps it in there all the time. Over time, the rock actually turns out to be a dragon egg that was kept warm by his body heat and hatches and is bonded with him.

I forget anything else really but I know that at some point he's in a castle and he's being taught magic and the dragon keeps growing in size and he has to also learn to ride the dragon but the dragon isn't big enough yet to be ridden. I think at some point the boy accidentally casts a fireball at the castle wall and causes some damage?

One important little detail is that these books had maps and drawing of details of the town and castle and other things relevant to the plot and they looked incredible; these maps and such were in the beginning and like ending parts of the book for the reader to check out and stuff.

I've been trying to Google and search for this book series for MONTHS, I'm hoping someone can help me find it. Oh!! And I know 100% that it's not *Eragon*!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall anything about the cover of this book?

Comment: Do you recall anything when it comes to other characters or when the book was published? For example: Did the main character have any friends helping him?

Comment: I can't remember much but I DO know that at that point in my life I didn't even bother with books that didn't have really cool art on the cover. As for other characters, I remember that there was a girl who helped him around the castle and that he had some older guy helping him learning magic. I have no idea when the book was published, only that I read I in my elementary school library like 8 years ago or something like that.

Comment: Sounds like Eragon, the first book of [The Inheritance Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inheritance_Cycle) series to me. Read it years ago, but don't remember enough details to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I recently read the Wikipedia summary of The Pit Dragon Trilogy where a boy hatches a baby dragon, has help from a girl, and seems to have some kind of training from an older man.

> Book 1: Dragon's Blood
> (1982) The story starts with a bond boy named Jakkin, working with many others in Sarkkhan's dragon nursery.
> Jakkin plans to steal a baby dragon from the farm to raise, hoping to train the dragon to fight and earn him enough money to buy himself out of bond. He eventually succeeds after having been badly injured during the day's work, as one of the hatchling dragons was "miscounted", thus no one would notice if it was missing, though it is eventually revealed that Sarkkhan had purposely given him the opportunity to steal the hatchling, knowing that Jakkin was literate and could read the breeder's chart posted on the door.
> Jakkin stows the tiny dragon away to an oasis that he had previously found. Akki, a girl at the nursery, eventually discovers his secret, and helps him, building a strong relationship in the process. After a full year of training and growing, Akki arranges a way for Jakkin and his beautiful red dragon to get to the pits. The red dragon’s first battle is hard won, and as it turned out too late for Jakkin, Sarkkhan was watching the fight. Fortunately, Sarkkhan took well to the idea of Jakkin raising the dragon, even admitting that he had known about Jakkin’s secret all along. Triumphant, after Sarkkhan tells him that it's a girl, Jakkin names his dragon "Heart’s Blood".
> As the story continues, Jakkin finds out more about the strained relationship between Sarkkhan and Akki. In the end, Akki leaves the nursery.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy

Comment: No that's not it, the boy never knew anything about dragons and dragons either didn't exist or weren't common.

Answer (score 0):

A stone that's actually a dragon's egg -- that occurs in James Haddock and Gus James' *Dragon's Envoy*. There is a castle and learning magic, and the stone *is* found by a boy. I *seem* to remember something about a fireball, also. But that's not a series and I remember no maps.

Farther back I half recall a stone that absorbs heat or energy and *might* have been an egg of some sort in one of the last books in *King's Dark Tidings* series - this *is* a series - and Book V is titled *Dragons and Demons*, so perhaps... but not much learning magic. And no maps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same book as well and just found it. If you're still looking it's the Septimus Heap series. First book is called Magyk.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the question?  The more details the better, since there are 2 other answers you need to distinguish this from.