Story-Identification: Fantasy book similar to Eragon
I have been looking for a book that I read when I was young. This would have been about 15...ish years ago, maybe a bit less. To me, it read a LOT like Eragon which was one of my favourite books at the time.
The book I'm looking for had:

a farm boy finding a dragon egg (?)
getting a scar on his palm/burn mark that was related to the plot
the setting was not modern, but in a fantasy-medieval (?) adjacent world

At this point I did stop reading because the plot was so familiar it felt 'ripped off' from Eragon. (I know, Eragon also borrowed heavily but I'm not here to debate that!)

Possible a duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271222/medieval-fantasy-book-about-a-boy-who-finds-a-rock-in-a-cave-or-something-like-t

As @Negdo points out, this is probably Jane Yolen's Pit Dragon series, or at least book one Dragon's Blood.  The points of congruence:

a farm boy finding a dragon egg (?)

Jakkin finds a missed dragon among the eggs and shards left from the brood of dragons hatching at the dragon farm.  He had been injured that day, but more importantly, he cuts himself on a shard of egg, and the dragon hatchling licks it for him.

getting a scar on his palm/burn mark that was related to the plot

I believe this is the cut that the dragon licked.  It later becomes clear that sharing blood with a dragon in this way links the two mentally.

the setting was not modern, but in a fantasy-medieval (?) adjacent world

The world is medieval in the sense that the setting of the first book is a dragon farm, and so very rural. The people are divided into classes or castes.  There is limited machinery, though, and Jakkin and his dragon do travel to a city.
In later books we find this is a backward world founded as a prison planet, and that all names with 'kk' in them are of the lower, prisoner, class (even the descendents are born into it).
Dragon's Blood was published in 1982, so it's unlikely it cribbed from Eragon.

